# Is there a way to exit power mode in the Scala interpreter?

Tags: scala, interpreter

I know power mode together with a slew of other options can be enabled in the interpreter with :power. Is there a way to leave power mode and return to a regular user?

Cheers,

Henry Henrinson

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is no.  The reason is that power mode imports various classes and adds to the classpath, and the JVM is not designed to unload classes and classpaths.  So although you could remove *some* aspects of power mode, it would be tricky to leave the JVM in the same state afterwards as if you hadn't used it, so you'd really only end up half removing it.